# Set Default Shape Scheme Spotfire

Tags: shapes, dropdown, spotfire

When using the "Shape by Column Values" in spotfire it assigns different default shapes for columns values.

If you change the default assigned shapes THEN switch columns THEN go back to the original column the new shapes I have picked have reverted to the original default assigned shapes.

Is there somewhere I can pre select the default shapes of these column values?

This is a problem because I am switching back and forth with a document property dropdown menu.

Thanks for any help